# Microsoft Access 2007: Export to multiple xml files

Tags: xml, ms-access-2007, export-to-xml

I have a table in my access database and I want to export each record to a single xml file. How can I achieve this?The only option I found was exporting the whole table to a single xml file.

Answer (score -2):

Any saved object can be exported to XML. This would include a saved QueryDef filtered to the records you want to export. The filtering can be done by tying the QueryDef's WHERE clause to controls on a form whose purpose is to allow the user to specify the desired record(s), or you can change the WHERE clause of the saved QueryDef in DAO code. I prefer the former to editing saved QueryDefs.

Comment: OK, someone please explain what's wrong with this answer to merit a downvote.

Comment: ...and a second downvote with no explanation. Stop being childish wankers -- stand by your downvotes with an explanation of your reason for registering it.